# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ros

I have a node in python 2.7. This node I am using to rotate the motor. After I have applied the formula of the calculating the number of encoder pulses per rotation to degree per rotation, and applying to the rest of the code, I get the error like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "read_write.py", line 167, in <module>
    controller = DynamixelController()
  File "read_write.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.test_motor_client(1)                #here we can put request order as 1 for the using id=14 and position= 1500; or as 2 is id same and position is 2500. The cases could be found in the server.py node  
  File "read_write.py", line 51, in test_motor_client
    self.read_write(response.id, response.position)
  File "read_write.py", line 130, in read_write
    dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION, dxl_goal_position[index])
  File "/home/kist/catkin_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/ros/src/dynamixel_sdk/protocol2_packet_handler.py", line 671, in write4ByteTxRx
    data_write = [DXL_LOBYTE(DXL_LOWORD(data)),   
  File "/home/kist/catkin_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/ros/src/dynamixel_sdk/robotis_def.py", line 63, in DXL_LOWORD
    return l & 0xFFFF 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'
```

My code which I'm trying to run and test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from controller_motor.msg import Motor
from controller_motor.srv import Motor2


if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
    def getch():
        return msvcrt.getch().decode()
else:
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    def getch():
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

from dynamixel_sdk import *                    # Uses Dynamixel SDK library


class DynamixelController(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #print("1")

        self.motor_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/motor_topic", Motor, self.motor_callback)
        self.test_motor_client(1)                #here we can put request order as 1 for the using id=14 and position= 1500; or as 2 is id same and position is 2500. The cases could be found in the server.py node
    
    def motor_callback(self, data):
        _id = data.id
        _position = data.position

        print("_id : {0}, _position : {1}".format(_id, _position))
        self.read_write(_id, _position)

    def test_motor_client(self, request):
        #print("2")
        rospy.wait_for_service('test_motor_service')
        try:
            proxy = rospy.ServiceProxy('test_motor_service', Motor2)
            response = proxy(request)
            print("response is id : {} position : {}".format(response.id, response.position))

            self.read_write(response.id, response.position)

        except rospy.ServiceException as e:
            print("Service call failed: %s"%e)
    
    def read_write(self, _id, _position):
        print("Start the node")
        _degreeposition = (0.088 * (_position))  #Degree per pulse multiple _position
        print(_degreeposition)
        print(type(_degreeposition))

        # Control table address
        ADDR_PRO_TORQUE_ENABLE      = 64               # Control table address is different in Dynamixel model
        ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION      = 116
        ADDR_PRO_PRESENT_POSITION   = 132
        #print(type(ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION))
        # Protocol version
        PROTOCOL_VERSION            = 2.0               # See which protocol version is used in the Dynamixel

        # Default setting
        DXL_ID                      = _id                 # Dynamixel ID : 14
        BAUDRATE                    = 1000000             # Dynamixel default baudrate : 57600
        DEVICENAME                  = '/dev/ttyUSB0'    # Check which port is being used on your controller
                                                        # ex) Windows: "COM1"   Linux: "/dev/ttyUSB0" Mac: "/dev/tty.usbserial-*"

        TORQUE_ENABLE               = 1                 # Value for enabling the torque
        TORQUE_DISABLE              = 0                 # Value for disabling the torque
        DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = 10.0           # Dynamixel will rotate between this value
        DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = _degreeposition            # and this value (note that the Dynamixel would not move when the position value is out of movable range. Check e-manual about the range of the Dynamixel you use.)
        DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD = 20                # Dynamixel moving status threshold

        index = 0
        dxl_goal_position = [DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE, DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE]         # Goal position


        # Initialize PortHandler instance
        # Set the port path
        # Get methods and members of PortHandlerLinux or PortHandlerWindows
        portHandler = PortHandler(DEVICENAME)

        # Initialize PacketHandler instance
        # Set the protocol version
        # Get methods and members of Protocol1PacketHandler or Protocol2PacketHandler
        packetHandler = PacketHandler(PROTOCOL_VERSION)

        # Open port
        if portHandler.openPort():
            print("Succeeded to open the port")
        else:
            print("Failed to open the port")
            print("Press any key to terminate...")
            getch()
            quit()


        # Set port baudrate
        if portHandler.setBaudRate(BAUDRATE):
            print("Succeeded to change the baudrate")
        else:
            print("Failed to change the baudrate")
            print("Press any key to terminate...")
            getch()
            quit()

        # Enable Dynamixel Torque
        dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write1ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_ENABLE)
        if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
        elif dxl_error != 0:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))
        else:
            print("Dynamixel has been successfully connected")

        while 1:
            print("Press any key to continue! (or press ESC to quit!)")
            if getch() == chr(0x1b):
                break

            # Write goal position
            dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION, dxl_goal_position[index])
            if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
                print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
            elif dxl_error != 0:
                print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

            while 1:
                # Read present position
                dxl_present_position, dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.read4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_PRESENT_POSITION)
                if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
                    print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
                elif dxl_error != 0:
                    print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

                print("[ID:%03d] GoalPos:%03d  PresPos:%03d" % (DXL_ID, dxl_goal_position[index], dxl_present_position))

                if not abs(dxl_goal_position[index] - dxl_present_position) > DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD:
                    break

            # Change goal position
            if index == 0:
                index = 1
            else:
                index = 0


        # Disable Dynamixel Torque
        dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write1ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_DISABLE)
        if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
        elif dxl_error != 0:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

        # Close port
        portHandler.closePort()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('read_write', anonymous=True)
    controller = DynamixelController()
    #controller.read_write(14, 1500)
```

My server node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from controller_motor.srv import Motor2, Motor2Response


def motor_info(req):
    print("receive the request : {}".format(req.order))
    if req.order == 1:
        _id = 14
        _position = 2000
        
    elif req.order == 2:
        _id = 14
        _position = 2047.5
       

    print("Response to this request id : {} and postiion : {}".format(_id, _position))
    #print("Response to this request id : {} and _degreepostiion : {}".format(_id, _degreeposition))
    return Motor2Response(_id, _position)
   

    
def motor_info_server():

    rospy.init_node('test_motor_service')
    s = rospy.Service('test_motor_service', Motor2, motor_info)
    print("Ready to response some id and scaled_position")

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    motor_info_server()
```

What is the problem and why the error like that is coming up?

Comment: What is your understanding of what that error message is saying?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are combining '`float`' and '`int`' values in `&` operation which is not permitted in python (No auto typecast).

It seems one of the source file does this operation:

```
l & 0xFFFF
```

where `l` is passed as a parameter. From what I can see in your code this is coming from your goal position values both of which are float.

```
dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_PRO_GOAL_POSITION, dxl_goal_position[index])
dxl_goal_position = [DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE, DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE]
DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = 10.0           
DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = _degreeposition 
_degreeposition = (0.088 * (_position))
```

Do you really need them to be `float` values? Can you convert these to `int`? For experimentation you can just pass dummy `int` values and check if that works. That will clarify if that is causing the error. If that fixes it, you need to figure out what is the correct value that needs to be passed (as per your code logic).

Comment: Good day, dear. Thank you for the fast answer. I will try and if it will work or not I will text it back :) I truly appreciate you help. Thank you very much and I wish you have a good day :)

Comment: I have tried to use the int instead of float and the calculation and motor are working well. Thank you dear DrSpill :) I truly appreciate your help and advice :)

Comment: Glad I could help. So, I believe this answer can be accepted? Thanks

Comment: Yeah dear, I think it could be accepted :) Thank you too :)
I wish you Happy Halloween :)